# Should factually incorrect questions be updated?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/56757/when-does-violent-civil-unrest-become-a-civil-war) says that

> where after three months of rioting, protesters and counter-protesters have begun shooting each other on the streets with a total of three dead

I left a comment pointing out there was a fourth shooting death (preceding the most recent events) which has since been deleted. (An Austin man drove his car into a group of protestors at the end of July, then shot and killed Garrett Foster when he was approached).

I realize politics.SE is more opinion based than other SE sites, but I thought it will still strive for accuracy. Therefore, I was hopeful the information from my comment would make it into the question, or at least stay as a comment under the question.

Possible resolutions:

- Nothing. My facts are wrong. Only three people have died.
- Nothing. It's ok for questions to be factually incorrect.
- Question is edited to include correct information.
- Original comment is restored.
- Something else? (This is a "discussion" post afterall)

Comment: Not a full answer, but in this case, I'd just remove the specific number from the question. This isn't a news site, so unless the specific number is important to the question (which it isn't here) then there's no reason to keep it or to create a bunch of noise on the main page by trying to keep it up to date. This isn't a general solution to the main question you asked, though, which is why this is a comment not an answer

Comment: I deleted your comment about a 4th person being shot because it stirred up another fight between pundits trying to control the narrative. And it's not even important for understanding what the question is asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with questions inspired by current events is that keeping the facts up to date with all the recent developments is 1. a lot of work and 2. often not really required for understanding the question.

The question is asking about the definition of civil war. It doesn't really make a difference if there are 3 or 4 victims of politically motivated violence. 3 or 300 might make a difference in this context. The question is perfectly understandable even if we don't list every single incident and then argue endlessly about how to frame the narrative around them in a way which appeases the political pundits of all sides. We spilled enough virtual blood about the phrasing "antifa and right-wing militia groups" in that question already.

Still, wrong information is worse than vague information. So I edited "total of three dead" to "at least three dead".

Comment: Regarding, `Should factually incorrect questions be updated?`. What would be a general answer to this question without being specific to the one mentioned in the question? Can I take it as a "yes"?

Comment: @SeverusSnape I would say "Yes, but within reason". For example, you should not update a question in a way which invalidates answers.